# Pull remote changes using git and upstart

Tags: linux, git, upstart

I would like to pull the changes as user 'ubuntu' during startup.

The upstart file is:

```
description "Custom startup script"

start on filesystem

script
  cd /var/www/gitstuff
  git checkout master
  git pull
end script
```

When I rebooted I got this log message:

```
Already on 'master'
Host key verification failed.^M
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have a feeling when the upstart script runs it is being executed as root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this for the pull statement:

```
git pull ubuntu@example.com:/etc/drupal/7/gitstuff
```

Also had to add keys to the root user

Answer (score 0):

try:

script

```
cd /var/www/gitstuff
su - ubuntu git checkout master
su - ubuntu git pull
```

end script

Comment: i dont have access to su but can sudo. i got it working though

Comment: If it runs as root it should be able to run with su, and you should not need to add keys to root user. Further debugging may be needed.